# What are Shadow Tabs in Magento's UI Object Hierarchy?

Tags: php, javascript, user-interface, magento

I'm poking around the Magento internals, and  within the Widget/Tab rendering hierarchy there's this concept of Shadow Tabs that I'm a little fuzzy on. When you're defining tabs for your form, you can bind it as a shadow tab

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->addTab('bundle_items', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Bundle Items'),
        'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/bundles', array('_current' => true)),
        'class' => 'ajax',
    ));
    $this->bindShadowTabs('bundle_items', 'customer_options');
}
```

The `bindShadowTabs` method is documents with

```
/**
 * Mark tabs as dependent of each other
 * Arbitrary number of tabs can be specified, but at least two
 *
 * @param string $tabOneId
 * @param string $tabTwoId
 * @param string $tabNId...
 */
public function bindShadowTabs($tabOneId, $tabTwoId)
```

The Javascript that leverages the PHP objects looks like

```
showTabContentImmediately : function(tab) {
    this.hideAllTabsContent();
    var tabContentElement = $(this.getTabContentElementId(tab));
    if (tabContentElement) {
        Element.show(tabContentElement);
        Element.addClassName(tab, 'active');
        // load shadow tabs, if any
        if (tab.shadowTabs && tab.shadowTabs.length) {
            for (var k in tab.shadowTabs) {
                this.loadShadowTab($(tab.shadowTabs[k]));
            }
        }
        if (!Element.hasClassName(tab, 'ajax only')) {
            Element.removeClassName(tab, 'notloaded');
        }
        this.activeTab = tab;
    }
    if (varienGlobalEvents) {
        varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('showTab', {tab:tab});
    }
},
```

From a basic reading, it's not entirely clear to me what the implications of making one tab "dependent" on another is.  Is this a simple "only render the `bundle_item` tab if the `customer_options` tab is rendered?  Or something more?

Comment: Not sure I would call this an answer, but different from what you said it seems if you load a tab that has shadow tabs, the shadow tabs will be loaded automatically. So, instead of having to explicitly load tabs A,B,C you just load A and B,C are loaded for you? Just a guess after a quick glance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like it means that whenever any of the tabs that are bound together as shadowTabs is displayed the other tabs in this grop will also be rendered.

so not "only render the `bundle_item` tab if the `customer_options` tab is rendered" but rather "whenever the `bundle_item` tab or the `customer_options` tab is rendered, render the other one as well".

not sure I like the metaphor of a shadow though.